# Create a new column in Power BI from values from a second table

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I need to add a new column in TableA with a value of a column in TableB.  One slight issue is that the return value in TableB will be a different column then what was being referenced.

TableA = column 1 has all the states

TableB = column 1 has all the states

TableB = column 2 has all the states and capitols in the same cell.

I want to go through each line in TableA and on a line that has a state, replace it with a state and capitol from TableB, Column2.  (Or make a new column)

If there is a way to simply use the value in TableA, column1 as a reference to find the row in TableB, Column2 that is great.